# What can we say about this eigenvalue problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Consider the generalised eigenvalue problem
\begin{equation}
\lambda \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}  v= \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}v. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Computing the eigenvalues in the usual way, i.e. by evaluating
\begin{equation}
\det \bigg( \begin{bmatrix} 
1-\lambda & 2 \\
3 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \bigg) = 1-\lambda-6=0, \tag{2}
\end{equation}
we find that the only eigenvalue is $\lambda =-5$; however, MATLAB provides $\lambda = -5$ and $\lambda = \infty$ when using $\texttt{eig}$. Is there something subtle I am missing here? Are eigenvalues of this problem even well-defined, since the inverse of the left-matrix does not exist?

Comment: I don't know much about generalised eigenvalue problems, but if I had to guess, I'd say that $\infty$ is listed as an eigenvalue, as the equation$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}v= \mu\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&1\end{bmatrix}v$$has non-trivial solutions for $\mu = 0$. The two generalised eigenvalues are related by each $\lambda$ corresponding to some $\mu^{-1}$, excluding zero. If we define $0^{-1}$ to be (complex) $\infty$ (and $\infty^{-1}$ to be $0$), then I can conceive how that would make certain theory more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a quirk of MATLAB and not universal. For example, Maple only returns $\lambda = -5$. It seems that MATLAB spits out $\lambda=\pm\infty$ whenever $rank(B)<dim(B)$. Let's look at the full output of eig() with your input:
$$
V = \begin{bmatrix}\frac 13 & 0 \\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix},
D = \begin{bmatrix}-5 & 0 \\ 0 & \infty\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The first column of $V$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda=-5$, but for the  second column vector we find
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&1\end{bmatrix}v
= \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
, \\ \infty \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}v
\overset?= \infty\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
In some sense, you could say $\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\infty\cdot 0 \\ \infty\cdot 0\end{bmatrix}$ is possible given the the indeterminate nature of $\infty\cdot 0$, making $v$ an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\infty$. In fact, as you showed, no second finite eigenvalue would be possible, so it's a choice between the above semi-nonsense or nothing at all.

It might be seen as convenient that MATLAB guarantees the expected dimensionality of the output, at the expense of having any further variables littered with `Inf`'s and `NaN`'s. As for any deeper meanings, I don't know. The brief documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html#bti99bb-1) doesn't mention these cases. Further questions include: How exactly does MATLAB choose the eigenvalues to use for $\pm \infty$ cases? How does it choose between $\infty$ and $-\infty$?

Comment: Seeing Theo Bendit's comment, I also agree with what they said.

Comment: I can't account for $-\infty$ though. If my assumption is correct, then $\infty$ has to be unsigned, as $0$ is unsigned.